# Filtro en DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, linq

Tengo un *DataGridView* cuyo *DataSource* es un *DataTable* con un esquema ya definido, tiene 6 columnas, *Id*, *Nombre_equipo*, *Serial*, ...

Lo que quiero hacer es un filtro a este *DataGridView* y que me muestre solo las filas que cumplen con mi condición y sin alterar el esquema. Esto lo quiero hacer sin una consulta a la base de datos. Solo tomando el *DataGridView* y su *DataSource*.

Había logrado algo con una consulta LINQ que encontré:

```
   string busqueda = this.txtBusqueda.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
            List<DataGridViewRow> rows = (from item in dgvVerEquipos.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                          let nombre_equipo = Convert.ToString(item.Cells["Nombre_equipo"].Value ?? string.Empty)
                                          where nombre_equipo.Contains(busqueda)
                                          select item).ToList<DataGridViewRow>();
```

Como no tengo mucho conocimiento con LINQ no sé que hacer después para asignar estas *rows* que me devolvió la consulta LINQ al *DataSource* del *DataGridView*

Comment: Es más sencillo hacer el filtro sobre la lista que cargas el datagrid y una vez hecho el filtro cargas otra vez el datasource con el listado resultante del filtrado. Puedes hacer el filtrado con LINQ o bucles o como quieras.

Comment: Puedes simplemente asignar `rows` al `DataSource` del `DataGridView`. Pero como te dicen en la respuesta, el mejor usar RowFilter probablemente.

Answer (score 1):

Si el filtro lo vas a aplicar antes de cargar los datos al DataGridView puedes aplicar el filtro al DataTable usando un dataview:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(tudatatable);
dv.RowFilter = "filtro";
```

Donde en "query" pones el filtro tipo "Id = 10". Y al datagridview le asignas ese dataview.

También puedes asignar directamente lo que te regresa Linq al datagridview.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es un filtro dinámico, es decir, que el usuario pueda filtrar los datos directamente, lo mas fácil es utilizar un control de terceros. Yo te recomiendo este que es gratuito: https://github.com/davidegironi/advanceddatagridview

Comment: Yo añadiría que en lugar de crear un `DataView`, puedes usar `RowFilter` directamente en el `DataSource` del `DataGridView` usando la propiedad `DefaultView`, asi: `(dataGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "filtro";`